# In Disassembler pipeline component - Send only last message out from GetNext() method

Tags: biztalk, message, pipeline

I have a requirement where I will be receiving a batch of records. I have to disassemble and insert the data into DB which I have completed. But I don't want any message to come out of the pipeline except the last custom made message.

I have extended `FFDasm` and called `Disassembler()`, then we have `GetNext()` which is returning every debatched message out and they are failing as there is subscribers. I want to send nothing out from `GetNext()` until Last message.

Please help if anyone have already implemented this requirement. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, if you're inserting into a database, how are you not processing the batch messages themselves?

Comment: Showing the relevant code in the question would help people answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send only one message on the GetNext, you have to call on Disassemble method to the base Disassemble and get all the messages (you can enqueue this messages to manage them on GetNext) as:

```
 public new void Disassemble(IPipelineContext pContext, IBaseMessage pInMsg)
 {
    try
    {    
       base.Disassemble(pContext, pInMsg);

       IBaseMessage message = base.GetNext(pContext);
       while (message != null)
       {    
           // Only store one message                   
           if (this.messagesCount == 0)
           {
              // _message is a Queue<IBaseMessage>
              this._messages.Enqueue(message);

              this.messagesCount++;
           }

           message = base.GetNext(pContext);
       }              
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // Manage errors 
    }
```

Then on GetNext method, you have the queue and you can return whatever you want:

```
public new IBaseMessage GetNext(IPipelineContext pContext)
{
   return _messages.Dequeue();
}
```

Comment: This sounds to be the solution. Let me try this, I will get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: MR. felixmondelo, My sincere thanks to you. This worked amazingly and that too we scored record performance by inserting 25K data to Table in less than a minute. Previously it took around 7 mins. That is simply superb. Your solution made it possible. A BIGGGG CHEERS to you!!!

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, **DO NOT DO THIS**.  It's a very risky and fragile pattern that eliminates much of the benefits of using BizTalk.  There are several better ways to accomplish this, even the <1 min performance.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to publish messages after disassemble stage to BizTalk message box db and use a db adapter to insert into database. Publishing messages to message box and using adapter will provide you more options on design/performance and will decouple your DB insert from receive logic. Also in future if you want to reuse the same message for something else, you would be able to do so.

Even then for any reason if you have to insert from pipeline component then do the following:

Please note, GetNext() method of IDisassembler interface is not invoked until Disassemble() method is complete. Based on this, you can use following approach assuming you have encapsulated FFDASM within your own custom component:

Insert all disassembled messages in disassemble method itself and enqueue only the last message to a Queue class variable. In GetNext() message then return the Dequeued message, when Queue is empty return null. You can optimize the DB insert by inserting multiple rows at a time and saving them in batches depending on volume. Please note this approach may encounter performance issues depending on the size of file and number of rows being inserted into db.

Comment: Hi Vikas, as of now, I am calling DBInsert SP from GetNext() as I get each individual record in GetNext(). My volume is huge about 25K flat file records which needs to be stored in DB first. With last message I trigger orch to poll each record and convert to SOAP request.

Comment: Hi Vikas, as of now, I am calling DBInsert SP from GetNext() as I get each individual record in GetNext(). My volume is huge about 25K flat file records which needs to be stored in DB first. With last message I trigger orch to poll each record and convert to SOAP request.  By calling SP in Disassembler() it will hit performance badly. That's why I am doing in GetNext() but for each GetNext() there is a dummy message sent out which I want to avoid. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should rather use a different approach, 25k is not a huge volume. You can let these messages publish to message box and from there you can send it to MSMQ. And then you can do whatever u want with them. MSMQ can be used on any BizTalk server you have and is part of Windows. You can use MSMQ adapter to send or receive messages from a queue and process them to go to both DB as well as create SOAP request.

Comment: No Vikas, that wont be accepted. This is the Architecture provided and I have to follow that. So there is no way to stop GetNext() to publish empty message to MsgBox?

Answer (score 0):

> I am calling DBInsert SP from GetNext()

Oh...so...sorry to say, but you're doing it wrong and actually creating a bunch of problems doing this. :(

This is a very basic scenario to cover with BizTalk Server.  All you need is:

1. A Pipeline Component to Promote BTS.InterchageID
2. A Sequential Convoy Orchestration Correlating on BTS.InterchangeID and using Ordered Delivery.
3. In the Orchestration, call the SP, transform to SOAP, call the SOAP endpoint, whatever you need.
4. As you process the Messages, check for BTS.LastInterchagneMessage, then perform your close out logic.

To be 100% clear, **there are no practical 'performance' issues here**.  By guessing about 'performance' you've actually created the problem you were thinking to solve, and created a bunch of support issues for later on, sorry again.  :(  There is no reason to not use an Orchestration.

As noted, 25K records isn't a lot.  Be sure to have the Receive Location and Orchestration in different Hosts.

Comment: Hi Johns, My requirement is such that I have to call SP from pipeline to avoid any loss of data. 1. Load data to DB 2. Create soap request for each record. 3. Get the SOAP response. 4. Batch all the responses and send to external system as FF.

Comment: Ok...even worse.  Sorry, but you're creating **potentially catastrophic gaps** by doing this.  Meaning, **you're creating a much greater probability of data loss** by calling the SP in the Pipeline vs using all the reliability features of BizTalk.  Using BizTalk as I describe is completely reliable and, to be blunt, much more reliable than the pattern you have implemented already.

Comment: Everything you describe should be done with an Orchestration and DB Adapters where you have built in retry, error handing etc.  Otherwise, you will have to basically re-write all this yourself.

Comment: The orch approach has a problem. 1. You need one orch just to call SP with retry and error handling.  2. you need one more orch to poll the DB, create request response. I want to eliminate the 1st orch by calling SP in DB and dont want that debatched message to publish to msgBox.

Comment: But those aren't "problems".  They're just not.  You can do all of that in one Orchestration if you want.  Though I would probably use two, maybe three called in succession.  There is nothing wrong with this, nothing.  In fact, that is the correct way.

Comment: **Very important.**  If someone is telling you to do it that way...well...they're wrong and don't understand how BizTalk works or how to create reliable high performance BizTalk apps.  The pattern you've implemented is dangerous for reliability and unnecessarily complicated for support and maintenance.  We can help you explain this to whoever provided this 'architecture'.

Comment: Sorry John, I have to do DB insert from Pipeline and Orchestration only to create SOAP req get response, etc..

Comment: Sorry, but why?  What are you plans to implement the failover, retry, logging, error handling, telemetry, etc. that you're giving up?  What diagnostic tools will you be writing?  Have you defined all the exception cases and plans for each?

Comment: Whoever is making you do this is dangerously wrong and I guarantee, this will cause problems for you and your app.  You need to make your management 100% clear this is a very bad and risky design because otherwise, it will become your problem.